# Voice biometric to unlock Android phone

Tags: android, voice, unlock

Hi i need to develop an application which unlocks the android phone through voice biometric.
Can any one help me out in doing this...

Comment: this is a bit broad, can you specify ?

Comment: ya sure. Its like voice authentication system to unlock the screen of the Android phone. The app should unlock the screen by taking voice of the registered user or authorised user as i/p. So that i can avoid the unautorised usage of my phone..

Answer (score 1):

There is a library to help you with this, PocketSphinx for Android

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for offline voice authentication I would suggest the following SDKs:

- [Neurotechnology](http://www.neurotechnology.com/verispeak.html)
- [Agnitio](http://www.agnitio-corp.com/products/commercial/speaker-verification)

They both support multiple platforms.