# Password validation using voice authentication in android

Tags: android, authentication, android-studio, android-support-library, voice-recognition

I want create a app which have a voice recognition validation. Suppose A wants to login in my app, first he/she done registration. During registration he/she record(Speak) some speech as a password. And when he wants to login again in the app he/she validate the password with his/her voice speech(Password). If same speech was spoken by others then its not validate.

If any one have any idea on this topic then please share.

Comment: You seem to be asking for a tutorial or off-site resource. That is off-topic for StackOverflow. Have you tried to use the `SpeechRecognizer` class?

Comment: yes but using speechRecognizer we get only text. I want to compare two voice. Voice biometric to unlock Android phone

Comment: To unlock the phone? Developers don't have access to override the lock screen functions for security reasons.

Comment: No, I want to use this functionality in my app. In my app at the time of login I want a voice authentication.

Comment: Do some research on voice biometric authentication for Android. I hit this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675430/voice-biometric-to-unlock-android-phone

Comment: visit this http://androidbite.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-voice-recognition-example.html

Comment: @Harshad by this solution we get only text. I want to compare two voice. Voice biometric to unlock Android phone

Comment: @BarmanInfo did you get a solution for this ? Am looking for exactly the same . can you please advice.

Comment: @Prabhuraj No, I am still looking for a solution, But I didn't get any proper solution.

Comment: @BarmanInfo Did you get any solution for this? I am looking for the same.